# D3js Force Directed Graph Link not found

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently trying to build a force directed graph with d3js v4. I have the following nodes and links, actually pretty simple

nodes

```
[
  {
    "id":"4d2b0275-5bc7-e611-81c4-00155df7ea33"
  },{
    "id":"b32b0275-5bc7-e611-81c4-00155df7ea33"
  }
]
```

links

```
[
  {
    "source":"4d2b0275-5bc7-e611-81c4-00155df7ea33",
    "target":"b32b0275-5bc7-e611-81c4-00155df7ea33"
  }
]
```

my forceSimulation setup is

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).distance(20).strength(1))
    .force("x", d3.forceX())
    .force("y", d3.forceY())
    .stop()
```

It throws an error on d3.forceLink(links) with `Uncaught Error: missing: 4d2b0275-5bc7-e611-81c4-00155df7ea33`.
so why is that error since the link is actually there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In D3, the default [link.id()](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#link_id) accessor function:

> allows each link’s source and target to be specified as a zero-based index into the nodes array.

This means that the source and the target are defined by the index of the node, as in this example in the API:

```
var links = [
    {"source": 0, "target": 1}, //from the first node to the second
    {"source": 1, "target": 2} //from the second node to the third
];
```

However, since you're defining the source and the target by the `id` of the node, not by its numeric index, you have to specify this id in the `id()` function:

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink(links)
     .id(function(d,i) {
         return d.id
     })
    .distance(20)
    .strength(1)
)
```