# d3Force's d3.forceLink error: node not found: <node id here>

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I see this related solution [D3js Force Directed Graph Link not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831024/d3js-force-directed-graph-link-not-found)

yet I get the error in the title - "VM2128 d3-force-3d:2 Uncaught Error: node not found: golfing_4_1"

```
function setNodeId(node) {
  return node.id; }

Graph.d3Force('link', d3.forceLink(graphData.links)
  .id( (d,i) => setNodeId(d) )
  // .strength( d => linkStrength(d) )
);
```

apparently(?) using version [2.1.1](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/commit/1eabfd08cf66633726f665a6ff336dc09d234ea4) of d3-force. Perhaps not even d3 itself

the minimally reproducible code:

```js
const graphData = {
  nodes: [{
      id: "Alice"
    },
    {
      id: "Bob"
    },
    {
      id: "George"
    }
  ],
  links: [{
      source: "Alice",
      target: "George"
    },
    {
      source: "George",
      target: "Bob"
    }
  ]
};

const elem = document.getElementById('3d-graph');
const Graph = ForceGraph3D()(elem)
  .graphData(graphData);

function setNodeId(node) {
  return node.id;
}

function linkStrength(link) {
  return (1 / link.sourceLevel);
}
Graph.d3Force('link', d3.forceLink(graphData.links)
  .id((d, i) => setNodeId(d))
  // .distance(200)
  // .strength( d => linkStrength(d) )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-force-3d"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/3d-force-graph"></script>
<div id="3d-graph"></div>
```

Comment: Please turn your code into a [mre]. Also let us know which version of d3 you're using, it matters a lot whether it's v2/3 or v6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem was that you needed to pass the entire `graphData` to your `d3.forceLink` function, not just `graphData.link`. However, I think the following solution is cleaner:

From the documentation of [`3d-force-graph`](https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph) for `Graph.d3Force()`:

> Getter/setter for the internal forces that control the d3 simulation engine. Follows the same interface as d3-force-3d's simulation.force. Three forces are included by default: 'link' (based on forceLink), 'charge' (based on forceManyBody) and 'center' (based on forceCenter).

This means that you can call the function with only a string `'link'` and you get an object of type `d3-force-3d.forceLink`, which is automatically applied and thus automatically has access to the right `graphData`. Then, you can set [`forceLink.id`](https://github.com/vasturiano/d3-force-3d#link_id) just like you did, but you can also set it later.

```js
const graphData = {
  nodes: [{
      id: "Alice"
    },
    {
      id: "Bob"
    },
    {
      id: "George"
    }
  ],
  links: [{
      source: "Alice",
      target: "George"
    },
    {
      source: "George",
      target: "Bob"
    }
  ]
};

const elem = document.getElementById('3d-graph');
const Graph = ForceGraph3D()(elem)
  .graphData(graphData);

function setNodeId(node) {
  return node.id;
}

const linkForce = Graph.d3Force('link')
  .id((d, i) => setNodeId(d));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-force-3d@2.2.0/dist/d3-force-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/3d-force-graph@1.67.3/dist/3d-force-graph.js"></script>
<div id="3d-graph"></div>
```